# Federate Active Directory to Ubuntu 12.04 using OpenLDAP

Tags: active-directory, ubuntu-12.04, openldap

Does anyone know how to federate from Microsoft Active Directory to Ubuntu 12.04 using OpenLDAP. My end goal is to be able to create the users in Active Directory and then give them SSO role based log in and access permissions to my Ubuntu servers.

Many thanks in advance,
Maria

Answer (score 0):

you need to synchronize users accounts between OpenLDAP and Active Directory.

This can be done with LSC ([LDAP Synchronization Connector](http://lsc-project.org)) for example. See this tutorial: http://lsc-project.org/wiki/documentation/tutorial/openldaptoactivedirectory

Comment: Thank you for the information. However, I want the target directory to be OpenLDAP and Active Directory the source. Can you recommend any documentation for accomplishing this?

Comment: With the documentation, it is possible to create a connector for AD -> OpenLDAP. You can join the mailing list to ask some help if you need.

Comment: Thank you so much! Also, do you know if I need to make any schema changes to my OpenLDAP? I found a page http://www.openldap.org/faq/data/cache/1461.html however, I don't all the information from my users, just username, display name, roles and password. In addition, looking at the files I need to edit they specifically say not to manually edit them.

Comment: No, you don't need to add schema. With LSC you can map AD attributes to OpenLDAP attributes.